# Python Correct Way to Use asyncio streams to open a connection, send and receive multiple transmissions, then close connection gracefully

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am asking where either my though process or my code is incorrect relative to using asyncio client streams to send data and receive responses from a server. When I call the method that disconnects the client an exception is thrown.  I am learning python asyncio and ran across exceptions during testing trying to close the client connection. I am trying to 1). Create a client connection to a server 2). leave the client connection open so that it can be used across multiple send/receive cycles 3). close the client connection gracefully when complete.

This is the class that contains the asyncio methods to create the stream writer.

```
  class hl7_client_sender:
      SB = b'\x1B'
      EB = b'\x1C'
      CR = b'\x0D'

      def __init__(self,address,port,timeout=-1,retry=3.0):
          self._resend=0
          self._timeout= timeout
          self._retry = retry
          #self._reader, self._writer = await asyncio.open_connection(address,port)
          self._address = address
          self._port = port
          self._writer = None
          self._reader = None

async def connect(self):
    self._reader, self._writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self._address,self._port)

async def disconnect(self):
    await self._writer.wait_closed()
```

and this is the code in my driver where the exception occurs during the call to disconnect

```
  #test send and respond
  import asyncio
  import string
  import unicodedata
  import simple_hl7_client
  import time
  ##open a connectino sleep 5 seconds then close###
  myclient = simple_hl7_client.hl7_client_sender('192.168.226.128',54321)
  asyncio.run(myclient.connect())
  time.sleep(3)
  asyncio.run(myclient.disconnect())
```

The exception occurs during the call to asycnio.run(myclient.disconnect())

This is the exception:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".\test_simple_hl7_client.py", line 11, in <module>
   asyncio.run(myclient.disconnect())
   File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py",           line 43, in run
      return loop.run_until_complete(main)
    File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
      return future.result()
    File "D:\data\FromOldPC\code\ASYNCIOTESTING\simple_hl7_client.py", line 23, in disconnect
      self._writer.close()
    File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 317, in close
      return self._transport.close()
    File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 663, in close
      self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
    File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in call_soon
      self._check_closed()
    File "C:\Users\billg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 479, in _check_closed
      raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
  RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: `asyncio.run()` is supposed to be the _single_ entry point into asyncio. You cannot just call `asyncio.run()` twice on the same asyncio-created objects because some of them (e.g. futures, queues) will store the event loop and will require to interact with the same event loop at all times. You should use a single `async def` that invokes `await myclient.connect(); await asyncio.sleep(3); await myclient.disconnect()`. Anything else is a recipe for failure.

Comment: thank you  user4815162342 I will try your suggestion and determine the result. Also you cleared up a point of confusion for me. Can you suggest any additional resources other than python read the docs that I should refer to?